# Get smooth Zoom In Zoom Out in Bing Map

Tags: bing-maps

I have angular 4 application and integrated Bing Map to display information in pushpin.

I did lot of googling but I couldn't find the solution to get smooth Zoom-In Zoom-Out operation in Bing Map.

Whenever I try to do zoom-in zoom-out either by mousewheel or click on (+) (-) button on the map I see below blurred & sticky image on map.

Also I checked the internet speed and it's more than enough (100 mbps). I haven't written any code on mousewheelchanged event.

Attached screenshot of blurred map when do zoom operation.

In short I am looking for smooth Zoom In Zoom Out operation like Google provide.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still I didn't find proper solution for zooming issue in BingMap but I came across following MSDN community forum question which is answered by **Ricky Brundritt**.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/93a2d940-d468-4e70-a06e-610c04105022/set-zoom-level-with-setview-with-animation-in-v8?forum=bingmapsajax

As per [rbrundritt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1245450/rbrundritt) Bing Map **V8 uses the HTML5 canvas and requires each frame to be drawn. This makes it difficult to animate smoothly.**

But seems like Microsoft has taken care of Bing Map challenges in their latest [Azure Maps Web Control](https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/).

Answer (score 1):

After searching a lot, I was able to get a smooth animation by [copying an example from Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/move-camera-ease). The example uses TweenJs, but note that the page seems to link to the wrong *tween* library. I was able to make it work using the following TweenJs: https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js.

In my case, I wanted to get a smooth map centering animation after selecting a pushpin. I think you should be able to adjust the following for zoom with no problem.

I also have to report that the output animation is smooth in moving the map, but any Bing's labels on top of the map (including pushpins and toponyms) do not always follow the movement with precision: sometimes the labels get rendered after the map animation moved already to the next frame, resulting in stuttering labels' animation. Which is a pity.

```js
function pushpinClicked(e)
{
    let selectedPin = e.target;
    DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('MauiBlazorApp', 'SetCoordinates', e.target.getLocation());
    selectedPin.setOptions({ color: 'red' });

    const mapLocationZoom = { center: map.getCenter() };

    new TWEEN.Tween(mapLocationZoom) // Create a new tween that modifies 'cameraOptions'.
        .to({ center: e.target.getLocation() }, 1000) // Move to destination in 1 second.
        .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Cubic.Out) // Use an easing function to make the animation smooth.
        .onUpdate(() => {
            map.setView(mapLocationZoom);
        })
        .start(); // Start the tween immediately.

    // Setup the animation loop.
    function animate(time) {
        TWEEN.update(time);
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```